# Can not detect CUDA device after restart Google Cloud Notebook

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, cuda

This issue happened when I restarted my cloud notebook server today.
Can be reproduced using the steps below:

1. Create a Google Cloud Notebook server with Tensorflow or Pytorch and GPU
2. After start the server, open the python console:

```
>>> import torch
>>> torch.cuda.is_available()
True
```

CUDA device is available until now.

3. Restart the server, and open the notebook again.

```
>>> import torch
>>> torch.cuda.is_available()
/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/cuda/__init__.py:52: UserWarning: CUDA initialization: CUDA unknown error - this may be due to an incorrectly set up environment, e.g. changing env variable CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES after program start. Setting the available devices to be zero. (Triggered internally at  /opt/conda/conda-bld/pytorch_1614378098133/work/c10/cuda/CUDAFunctions.cpp:109.)
  return torch._C._cuda_getDeviceCount() > 0
False
```

`nvidia-smi` command works fine.

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 450.80.02    Driver Version: 450.80.02    CUDA Version: 11.0     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Tesla T4            Off  | 00000000:00:04.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   43C    P0    16W /  70W |      0MiB / 15109MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

```
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2020 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Thu_Jun_11_22:26:38_PDT_2020
Cuda compilation tools, release 11.0, V11.0.194
Build cuda_11.0_bu.TC445_37.28540450_0
```

This issue can also be reproduced by using TensorFlow. How to fix this kind of case?

Comment: ...am I the only one thinking a "cloud notebook server" looks a lot like a multiple oxymoron?

Answer (score 0):

Option1:
Upgrade a Notebooks instance's environment. Refer the [link](https://cloud.google.com/notebooks/docs/upgrade#use-the-gcloud-command-line-tool_1) to upgrade.
Notebooks instances that can be upgraded are dual-disk, with one boot disk and one data disk. The upgrade process upgrades the boot disk to a new image while preserving your data on the data disk.

Optione2:
Connect to the notebook VM via SSH and run the commands [link](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads?target_os=Linux&target_arch=x86_64&Distribution=Debian&target_version=10&target_type=deb_network).
After execution of the commands, the cuda version will update to 11.3 and the nvidia driver version to 465.19.01.
Restart the notebook VM.

**Note:** Issue has been solved in gpu images. New notebooks will be created with image version M74. About new image version is not yet updated in [google-public-issue-tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/191612865) but you can find the new image version M74 in console.